Dynamically registering multiple flows and running in parallel
I am dynamically registering multiple IntegrationFlows:
private IntegrationFlowContext context;

context.registration(flow1()).register();
context.registration(flow1()).register();

IntegrationFlow flow1(){
   return IntegrationFlow.from(messageSource....)
   p-> p.poller(...
  .channel("outhannel")
  .get()
}

MessageSource<Object> messageSource() {
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = ....
}

I need each of them to run in different thread , and write to same outChannel.
How to do that?
I know that inside each flow i can set:  taskExecutor(...) on the poller, but as I understand it just each poller will run in multithread, but i need the flow (jdbcadapter) to run in a thread.

The poller functionality is already based on the TaskScheduler. So, your JdbcPollingChannelAdapter instances are going to be called from those scheduler's thread. You might consider to increase the pool size for default TaskScheduler in Spring Boot, which is 1 by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/task-execution-and-scheduling.html.
That taskExecutor() indeed can help you to shift scheduling work to a different thread. So, not clear what is your concern here then.

so if I set for example task Executor with pool size n, and I register n adapters, all n adapters will call the sql query in parallel (n threards)? and will push data to same outhannel (DirectChannel), do i need to do anything there also?

Correct. See the logic in the AbstractPollingEndpoint: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/endpoint/AbstractPollingEndpoint.java#L346-L360. As you see that pollForMessage() is called as a part of this.taskExecutor.execute().  Well, almost in parallel since the behavior slightly depends on the TaskScheduler.

I assume each thread poll will wait until the @ServiceActivator that bounded to outhannel handles the polled messages, correct?

Also I have a doubt, in case there is only one adapter, and I assign task executor with n threads, only 1 will be used in this case?

Not a fact. Since you switch threads from scheduler to an executor, the schedule one is ready to perform another task. This one is going to be pushed to that executor. Indeed this new task might be performed on a different thread.

I guess I need to have the poll + handling of the polled messages as atomic operation . can i achieve that?

Yes. Without taskExecutor. Just rely on the TaskScheduler and see its pool size as I stated in my answer.
